# document.querySelector direct descendant issue

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="active">
    Books
    <ul>
      <li>See All</li>
      <li>
        Crime
        <ul class="expected">
          <li>Agatha Cristie</li>
          <li>Tom Clancy</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        Cooking
        <ul>
          <li>Delia Smith</li>
          <li>Jamie Oliver</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      Electronics
      <ul>
        <li>See All</li>
        <li>TVs</li>
      </ul>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and using this selector:

```
var activeItem = document.querySelector('.active');
var nestedMenu = activeItem.querySelector('ul > li > ul');

nestedMenu.classList.add('actual');
```

Can someone explain why the selector `ul > li > ul` isn't getting a third-depth `ul.expected`, but the top-level `ul.menu` ?

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dczat6g7/

This seems to be an invalid result, I would expect either the `.expected` UL to be found or null. Am I missing something?

Comment: Post your relevant code inside the question, don't expect us to follow links around the internet in order to help. Code on JS Fiddle is a *bonus*, and incredibly helpful, but the "*[mcve]*" code must be in your question (there's an explicit close reason for questions that don't contain the relevant code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the MDN docs for [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector):

> Returns the first element that is a descendant of the element on which it is invoked that matches the specified group of selectors.

This does not say that the selector is applied starting at the designated not, only that the results of the selector are filtered to descendent of the designated node.

Ie. it returns the first node which is both in the set of nodes matched by the selector – globally – and is a descendant of `activeItem`.

And the one node that gets `.actual` applied meets both criteria.

There is no universal – across all browsers – CSS selector method that will operate relative to another node. For non-IE you can include [`:scope`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope) in your CSS to operate relative to the designated elements. A universal solution would be to use an id selector. So you could add an id to your starting node (or use its existing id) and then include that id in the CSS selector.

Comment: "As far as I know there is no CSS selector method that will operate relative to another node." That selector is :scope, as in querySelector(':scope > ul > li > ul')

Comment: Thanks - I guess MDN could use a wording change to be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's another level down that's why

```
var activeItem = document.querySelector('.active');
var nestedMenu = activeItem.querySelector('ul > li > ul > li > ul');

nestedMenu.classList.add('actual');
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dczat6g7/1/)

So if you break that down, that is the third level

[ul > li] 1st Level

[ul > li] 2nd Level

[ul] Start of 3rd Level

What you had was the second level